Is Geckodriver available for 64-bit Windows?
Previous distributions for geckodriver included clear names for windows like *win32.zip and *win64.zip. Now there are *win-aarch64.zip and *win32.zip.
While it’s clear with the win32 version - for 32 bit systems, then what is win-aarch64? Is geckodriver no longer available for 64-bit Windows?

I do see both (32 and 64)bits versions here for this offtopic question

geckodriver-v0.35.0-win64.zip is available at https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.35.0. When browsing directly to the Releases tab, you may have to click on the Show all 13 assets link.
